# How does this for-loop within this dictionary work exactly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set-comprehension

Currently I'm learning Python text sentiment module via this online course and the lecturer failed to explain in enough detail how this piece of code works. I tried searching each piece of code individually to try piece together how he did it but it makes no sense to me.

1. So how does this code work? Why is there a for loop within dictionary braces?
2. What is the logic behind `x` before the `for y in emotion_dict.values()` then `for x in y` at the end?
3. What is the purpose behind `emotion_dict=emotion_dict` within the parentheses? Wouldn't just `emotion_dict` do?

   ```
    def emotion_analyzer(text,emotion_dict=emotion_dict):
    #Set up the result dictionary
        emotions = {x for y in emotion_dict.values() for x in y}
        emotion_count = dict()
        for emotion in emotions:
            emotion_count[emotion] = 0

        #Analyze the text and normalize by total number of words
        total_words = len(text.split())
        for word in text.split():
             if emotion_dict.get(word):
                  for emotion in emotion_dict.get(word):
                      emotion_count[emotion] += 1/len(text.split())
        return emotion_count
   ```

Comment: The `emotion_dict=emotion_dict` is giving the function a default-value, which will be used if no value is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1 and 2

The line `emotions = {x for y in emotion_dict.values() for x in y}` uses a *set comprehension*. It builds a set, not a dictionary (though dictionary comprehensions also exist and look somewhat similar). It is shorthand notation for

```
emotions = set()  # Empty set
# Loop over all values (not keys) in the pre-existing dictionary emotion_dict
for y in emotion_dict.values():
    # The values y are some kind of container.
    # Loop over each element in these containers.
    for x in y:
        # Add x to the set
        emotions.add(x)
```

The `x` right after the `{` in the original set comprehension signifies which value to store in the set. In all, `emotions` is just a set (with no repeats) of all elements within all containers within the dictionary `emotion_dict`. Try printing out `emotion_dict` and `emotion` and compare.

## 3

In the function definition,

```
def emotion_analyzer(text, emotion_dict=emotion_dict):
```

the `emotion_dict=emotion_dict` means that the *local* variable with name `emotion_dict` gets set to the *global* variable similarly named `emotion_dict`, if you do not pass anything as the second argument. This is an example of a [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Comment: Thanks for your response that makes sense now that I looked up set comprehension. Appreciate the clear break down of each part.